# Conversion between object and decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Why can't I convert object to decimal (code is below, `record["Cost"]` is equal `1 (int)`)?

I get following error

***'can not unbox record["Cost"]'***

I will use `TryParse` method, but I don't understand what is source of this error.

```
cost = (decimal?) record["Cost"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `record["Cost"]` is a boxed int. Unboxing conversions only allow you to convert to the *same* type. (At least broadly; there are a few differences, but they're irrelevant here.)

What you should do is unbox to `int` and then convert to `decimal?`:

```
cost = (decimal?) (int) record["Cost"];
```

Or if `cost` is already declared as type `decimal?`, you can use the implicit conversion:

```
cost = (int) record["Cost"];
```

Comment: What if `record["Cost"]` could be either a null reference or a boxed `int`, and he wants a nullable `decimal`? Then he might want `decimal? cost = (int?) record["Cost"];`. We don't know if this is the case, though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, that's a possibility.